# This code works... but why? (Inserting a number in a sorted array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, if-statement

The objective with this code is to insert a number in an array, which should be first sorted by ascending order. The code should return the index where that number belongs in the sorted array.

Simple enough, but the way this next example was solved, baffles me:

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    if (arr[a] >= num) return a;
  }

  return arr.length;
}

getIndexToIns([1028, 64, 16, 32, 8, 256, 128], 50);
```

This code works, but I can't understand why using **return *arr.length;*** at the end, results in that index we need. Shouldn't that give us the actual length of the complete aray? Why does it results in the index of the inserted number should be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you see the `return a;` statement in the loop?

Comment: the test provided in your function call does not even make it to the last return statement

Comment: I would say this is an example of bad coding style - the most important `return` in this function is also the less visible one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `for` loop, doesn't find a smaller `a` to insert the element, the last possible solution is `arr.length`

```
arr                arr.length      insert(arr.length, "X")
-------------------------------------------------------------
[]                 0               ["X"]
["A"]              1               ["A", "X"]
["A", "B"]         2               ["A", "B", "X"]
["A", "B", "C"]    3               ["A", "B", "C", "X"]
...
```

Comment: This! I wasn't aware that the *return arr.length* in this case acted as an *else* statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The function works ok - perhaps a tweak here or there:

```js
let array = [1028, 64, 16, 32, 8, 256, 128];

function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    if (arr[a] >= num) {
      return a;
    }
  }
  return arr.length;
}

console.log(getIndexToIns(array, 10000));
```

What looks confusing is that you are expecting **return arr.length** to happen every time the function is called.  That will only happen if no value in the array is greater than the parameter **num** value.  If a number is found that is greater than that, the **return a** line kicks in and immediately ends execution of the function, so **return arr.length** won't be reached.  You can see this in this snippet as I've set the **num** value to 10000.  Of course, you don't really need to sort the array to find the first number that is greater than **num**

Update:  This is how I would do it (except I would have the sort function outside of this function):

```
function getIndexToInsert(arr, num) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  let result = -1;
  
  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    if (arr[a] >= num) {
      // if we have found a number greater than num, set the result to the current index position and break out of the for loop
      result = a;
      break;
    }
  }
  // now we have either -1 (not found) or a number >= 0 (index of item found)
  return result;
}

let newvalue = 547;

let pos = getIndexToInsert(array, newvalue);
  // now test the result
if (pos == -1) {
  // no existing value is greater than newvalue, so pos remained as -1
  // so, just add newvalue to the end of the array
  array.push(newvalue);
} else {
  // otherwise, we have the index number of the first value that is > newvalue
  // so, insert the newvalue there instead
  array.splice(pos, 0, newvalue);
}

console.log(array);
```

Doing it this way makes it clear what is happening and what values we expect to get back - either `-1` or an index position.

Comment: Now I see it! The *return arr.length* works as an *else* statement. Thank you!

Comment: Sort of - it's a catchall.  I've updated my code to include another way to do it which, I hope, makes it a bit clearer and removes any `what does this bit do` ambiguity

Comment: The other alternative, of course, is to just push the value onto the end of the array and then sort the array :)